# What are some beanstalkd libraries for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, beanstalkd

One of them is [Stalker](https://github.com/adamwiggins/stalker), but I heard there are other good ones. Anyone know the other beanstalk libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the other primary one is `beanstalk-client-ruby`: http://beanstalk.rubyforge.org/

See Beanstalkd's own client list: https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/wiki/client-libraries

Answer (score 1):

Another one is [backburner](https://github.com/nesquena/backburner), which works well with Rails and Sinatra. For viewing stats on your beanstalkd queues, you might also try [beanstalkd_view](https://github.com/denniskuczynski/beanstalkd_view)